# Ansible : compare commands stdout with an existing folder at different location

Tags: ansible

I am searching for an existing software version available in VM1 and trying to compare its version with a latest version available in a vm2 (latest versions are stored in a specific folder in vm2) using ansible playbook

I am trying to run playbook in a Linux server and search current installed version with latest available (stored in a specific folder )

```
ok: [gxd5488] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "rpm -qa | grep Tanium*",
        "delta": "0:00:01.274237",
        "end": "2019-10-25 13:09:37.579902",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2019-10-25 13:09:36.305665",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "TaniumClient-7.2.314.3476-1.rhe7.x86_64",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "TaniumClient-7.2.314.3476-1.rhe7.x86_64" ------ (wanted to take this out put  and compare )
        ],
        "warnings": [
            "Consider using yum, dnf or zypper module rather than running rpm"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of interpretation on this question unless you also post the tasks that you are using to gather the version number of both servers.  Are they both in the same play as well?  Posting that kind of information will help us give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have used 'register' to store above example under a variable name 'version', use below condition when you update version in VM1. (considering VM2 version is 8.0.0)

```
when: "version.stdout.split('.')[0] >= '8.0.0'"
```

or if you have variable of VM2's latest version stored, use it to compare.

```
when: "version.stdout.split('.')[0] >= {{ VM2 version }}"
```